# Is linux.org still maintaining their OS? Who's using it?

Tags: linux, distributions

There are many distributions of linux, so is [linux.org](http://linux.org) still maintaining their orginal OS? If yes, then why use it when you can get Ubuntu, Debian, Centos, etc?

Comment: i mean: can you still download LINUX os, on servers and desktops?  i know it might be used somewhere else, but my question is for servers and desktops

Comment: I don't think there was ever a Linux distro on linux.org.  That domain appears to be owned by a web design company. I don't understand your question in fact. There's a Linux kernel (http://kernel.org), then a bunch of distributions for all kinds of machines, some of which you stated.

Comment: @Mat Oh! I thought that linux.org offers their LINUX version lol!

Comment: [The last working snapshot](http://web.archive.org/web/20110310062037/http://www.linux.org/) available [at the archive](http://wayback.archive.org/web/*/http://linux.org) is from March 10 2011.

Comment: @sr_ thank you so much!!!!!!! there's or there was lol an original release by linux.org itself! that what i needed to know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The defining component of Linux is the Linux kernel. However, we always say linux which means GNU/Linux. [Here is the explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux). Every Linux distro has its own official website. [DistroWatch](http://distrowatch.com)
is a website that show almost all linux distros.